# Problems on a simple contract

Tags: contract-design

I am a new learner in solidity.

My simple contract cannot compile in remix and I do not know how to fix the error in line 18 (the declaration of uploadStudent). The error is 'Data location can be specified for array, struct, or mapping types, but 'memory' was given.'

May I have your help?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract simple {
  mapping(uint => studentFile) public studentfiles;

  uint studentCount;
  
  struct studentFile {
    uint studentId;
    string studentName;
    uint age;
  }

  constructor() public {
      studentCount=0;
  }

  function uploadStudent(string memory _studentName, uint memory _age) public {

    // Increment student id
    studentCount ++;

    // Add File to the contract
    studentfiles(studentCount) = studentFile(studentCount, _studentName, _age);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify a data location for number types. Simply replace this bit:

```
uint memory _age
```

with

```
uint _age
```

and this line:

```
studentfiles(studentCount) = studentFile(studentCount, _studentName, _age);
```

with

```
studentfiles[studentCount] = studentFile(studentCount, _studentName, _age);
```

and your contract will compile. As the error mentions, you can only specify a memory location for array, sturct, or mapping types. In Solidity, strings are essentially byte arrays, which is why you can set the data location for `_studentName`.

You can read more about data locations in the Solidity documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/types.html#data-location).

Comment: No problem. Please mark the question as answered if it helped you out.